# How to launch a watchOS app from a notification?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, watchos

I've started to learn `watchKit` and `watchOS`.

After finding out how to handle notifications coming from a button set inside `PushNotificationPayload.apns`, I would like to set up my own notification that is going to fire at a given time, wake up the user with some kind of notification while the app is in the background, and possibly launch the app.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

In watchOS 2, this required scheduling the notification on the phone.  It wasn't possible to wake up the watch app from the phone.

In watchOS 3, you can now use the new [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications) framework to schedule, deliver, and handle local notifications right on the watch.

You can display an actionable notification on the watch, which can open your watch app from the notification.

WWDC 2016 covered this material in two [Introduction to Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/) and [Quick Interaction Techniques for watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/211/) sessions.

Comment: That's interesting (UserNotifications). But it means I have to install the beta version of Xcode.
And about "display an actionable notification on the watch": how do I do that? Sorry if my questions do not show much expertise, I only started to touch WatchKit about 2 days ago, and only part time :)

Comment: That question is fairly broad. I'd encourage you to watch the intro videos. You'll learn more from them in general, and they will give you a good foundation to build on. All the sessions contain lots of code examples and demos, and some also have sample code that you can download and run. If you're stuck, please post the notification code you tried, along with a specific description of the problem.  It's easier to address a specific issue, than to try to explain what you'd have to do to accomplish what you asked. :)